# Oracle SQL Optimization : hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

I have this query that get list of records and traces the genealogy of each record but it runs forever. Can anyone help me improve the performance?

```
  WITH root_nodes AS
  (SELECT distinct dlot.dim_lot_key AS lot_key, facility, lot
    FROM pedwroot.dim_lot dlot
    JOIN AT_LOT a
    ON (a.at_lot = dlot.lot AND a.at_facility = dlot.facility)
   WHERE (dlot.has_test_lpt = 'Y'
      or dlot.has_post_test_lpt = 'Y') and a.at_facility = 'MLA'),

    upstream_genealogy AS
    (SELECT /*+ INDEX(fact_link_lot IX_R_FLLOT_DLOT_2)*/DISTINCT CONNECT_BY_ROOT         
           fllot.dst_lot_key AS root_lot_key,
           fllot.src_lot_key
     FROM pedwroot.fact_link_lot fllot
     CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR fllot.src_lot_key = fllot.dst_lot_key
     START WITH fllot.dst_lot_key IN (SELECT lot_key FROM root_nodes)),

   at_lst AS
    (Select *
      FROM pedwroot.dim_lot dlot_lst
       JOIN upstream_genealogy upgen
        ON (upgen.src_lot_key = dlot_lst.dim_lot_key)
        where dlot_lst.has_assembly_lpt = 'Y')

      SELECT distinct dlot_root.lot         AS AT_LOT,
            dlot_root.facility    AS AT_FACILITY,
            dfac_root.common_name AS AT_SITE,
            dlot_root.LTC         AS AT_LTC,
            al.lot                AS AT_LST,
            dlot_src.lot          AS FAB_LOT,
            dlot_src.facility     AS FAB_FACILITY,
            dfac_src.common_name  AS FAB_SITE
       FROM upstream_genealogy upgen
       JOIN at_lst al
       ON (upgen.root_lot_key = al.root_lot_key)
       JOIN pedwroot.dim_lot dlot_src
       ON (upgen.src_lot_key = dlot_src.dim_lot_key)
       JOIN pedwroot.dim_lot dlot_root
       ON (upgen.root_lot_key = dlot_root.dim_lot_key)
       JOIN pedwroot.fact_lot flot
       ON (dlot_root.dim_lot_key = flot.lot_key)
       JOIN pedwroot.dim_facility dfac_root
       ON (flot.facility_key = dfac_root.dim_facility_key)
       JOIN pedwroot.dim_facility dfac_src
      ON (flot.fab_facility_key = dfac_src.dim_facility_key)
       WHERE dlot_src.has_fab_lpt = 'Y';
```

Below is the explain plan of this query
[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry the explain_plan is unreadable due to resolution

Comment: but let me ask - what indexes exist?

Comment: Better copy the execution plan as plain text to something like http://pastebin.com/

Comment: please view the explain plan image in a new tab and you can see a clearer copy, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sudden change in cardinality from 11 million to 1 looks like a problem.  Remove tables and predicates from the query until you find out exactly what is causing that poor estimate.

Most of the time these issue are caused by bad statistics, try gathering stats for all the related tables.  (I can think of dozens of other potential problems, but it's probably not worth guessing until you can shrink the problem a little.)

Comment: what do you mean by remove tables and predicates from the query? And if it is ok, can you guide on the explain plan, I am not quite understand, thanks

Comment: Break your query into smaller parts, run them, and compare the actual number of rows with the estimated number of rows (cardinality).   Cardinality estimates will usually get worse as the query gets larger, you want to find the first place it goes wrong.  For example, if you only run root_nodes, what are the actual and estimated number of rows?

Comment: I tried to run each of the small queries, and found out that the upstream_genealogy takes forever to run, but i dont know how to improve it, any suggestions?